# Referencing yourself inside of a struct

Tags: struct, go

Let's say I have a type that's a struct like so:

```
type Authorization struct {
    Username string
    Password string
    Handler  func(http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc
}
```

And I have an array of these:

```
type Authorizations map[string]*Authorization
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
var auth = Authorizations{
    "test": *Authorization{
        "someusername",
        "somepassword",
        self.BasicAuth,
    },
}
```

Assume that self.BasicAuth (which obviously doesn't work) is a method on the Authorization type. What is the syntactically correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't refer to a value inside its own declaration. You need to initialize the value first, then you can assign the method you want to use to Handler.

```
testAuth := &Authorization{
    Username: "someusername",
    Password: "somepassword",
}
testAuth.Handler = testAuth.HandleFunc

auths := Authorizations{
    "test": testAuth,
}
```